# Filtering with just one parameter in a list of firestore collection in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a chat app where people join groups, I have been able to create the groups and allow people to join in, anytime a user joins I save the group object into the user collection, so as to fetch for some other time, now what I want to achieve is fetching all user where group ID is the same value. here is what I have tried.

```
 getUsersInCircle(String circleID) async {
userList.clear();
try {
  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> ref = await db
      .collection(AppStrings.users)
      .where("circles", arrayContains: circleID)
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> value) {
    if (value.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      userList.assignAll(
          value.docs.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e.data())).toList());
      print(value.docs.first.data());
    } else {
      print("no data");
    }
    return value;
  });

  return ref;
} catch (e) {

  print(e.toString());
}
```

}

This is what my firestore database looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU8k9.png)

What I want to filter by is the circle Id but it does not return any data

Answer (score 0):

i think i found the problem, you are storing an map inside the circles array, not as a normal array.

this is the difference between an map and array in Firestore

[map vs array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E2G1.png)

Query an array:

```
where("circles", arrayContains: circleID)
```

Query an map

```
where("circles.circleID", isEqualTo: circleID)
```

Comment: I still don't understand this enough how do i access the circle id from the list of circles since its an array, not a map